# Slow Query - Changing it producing odd results

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

I have a query I am trying to optimize but the results aren't making sense to me.

It takes roughly 7 seconds to complete this:

```mysql
SELECT users.*,states.name AS state_name, CONCAT_WS(" - ",L1.updated_at,L1.last_location) AS last_activity,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses WHERE user_id = users.id) AS num_products_total,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 5) AS num_products_plt,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 7) AS num_products_ce,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 6) AS num_products_sh,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 8) AS num_products_vc,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 9) AS num_products_book
FROM users LEFT JOIN states ON (states.id = users.state_id) 
LEFT JOIN logs_user_login AS L1 ON L1.id = (SELECT L2.id FROM logs_user_login AS L2 WHERE L2.user_id = users.id ORDER BY L2.updated_at DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY users.id desc LIMIT 0,20;
```

If I modify (remove counts of course types) to this is takes 2.5 seconds:

```mysql
SELECT users.*,states.name AS state_name, CONCAT_WS(" - ",L1.updated_at,L1.last_location) AS last_activity
FROM users LEFT JOIN states ON (states.id = users.state_id) 
LEFT JOIN logs_user_login AS L1 ON L1.id = (SELECT L2.id FROM logs_user_login AS L2 WHERE L2.user_id = users.id ORDER BY L2.updated_at DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY users.id desc LIMIT 0,20;
```

If I modify (remove get last login log) to this is takes 0.005 seconds:

```mysql
SELECT users.*,states.name AS state_name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses WHERE user_id = users.id) AS num_products_total,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 5) AS num_products_plt,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 7) AS num_products_ce,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 6) AS num_products_sh,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 8) AS num_products_vc,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 9) AS num_products_book
FROM users LEFT JOIN states ON (states.id = users.state_id)  ORDER BY users.id desc LIMIT 0,20;
```

**UPDATE**
I narrowed it down further but still doesn't make sense to my why this is happening. If I remove the L1 table references from the SELECT then the query goes 0.005 again even with the original query that took 7 seconds, the only difference is not grabbing the values from L1.

It takes roughly 0.005 seconds to complete this (Only took the L1 returns out of the select):

```mysql
SELECT users.*,states.name AS state_name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses WHERE user_id = users.id) AS num_products_total,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 5) AS num_products_plt,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 7) AS num_products_ce,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 6) AS num_products_sh,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 8) AS num_products_vc,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_courses LEFT JOIN courses ON (courses.id = user_courses.course_id) WHERE user_courses.user_id = users.id AND courses.type_id = 9) AS num_products_book
FROM users LEFT JOIN states ON (states.id = users.state_id) 
LEFT JOIN logs_user_login AS L1 ON L1.id = (SELECT L2.id FROM logs_user_login AS L2 WHERE L2.user_id = users.id ORDER BY L2.updated_at DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY users.id desc LIMIT 0,20;
```

Why would I have such a HUGE hit just returning the value from the joined table? It's returning a NULL or a small string under 64 characters.

Comment: @MatBailie Yes sorry as I narrowed it down I thought I could streamline it a lot from the original and make it easier to follow and did that before any answers, then figured it out and was posting an answer to my own Q right as someone else posted from the original post. I rolled it back.

Comment: What is the intent of the query?  I would expect to see a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the log entry, you don't need a join on a correlated sub-query (which accesses the logs twice, once by user and timestamp, once by id), you can just use a scalar sub-query, much like you did for the course counts.

Conversely, the course counts can be calculated in one pass, using conditional aggregation, reducing passes over those tables.

```sql
SELECT
  users.*,
  states.name AS state_name,
  user_course_count.*,
  (
    SELECT
      CONCAT_WS(" - ", updated at, last_location)
    FROM
      logs_user_login
    WHERE
      user_id = users.id
    ORDER BY
      updated_at DESC LIMIT 1 
  )
    AS last_activity
FROM
  users
LEFT JOIN
  states
    ON states.id = users.state_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    user_courses.user_id,
    COUNT(*) AS num_products_total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN courses.type_id = 5 THEN 1 END) AS num_products_5,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN courses.type_id = 6 THEN 1 END) AS num_products_6,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN courses.type_id = 7 THEN 1 END) AS num_products_7,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN courses.type_id = 8 THEN 1 END) AS num_products_8,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN courses.type_id = 9 THEN 1 END) AS num_products_9
  FROM
    user_courses
  INNER JOIN
    courses
      ON courses.id = user_courses.course_id
  GROUP BY
    user_courses.user_id
)
  AS user_course_count
    ON users.id = user_course_count.user_id
ORDER BY
  users.id DESC LIMIT 0,20;
```

Comment: Thanks the key seemed to be moving the logs_user_login to inside the select instead of left join below.